# How to remove an item from a jlist

Tags: java, swing

I have a Jlist which is populated with books, however, what I would like to do is that once one of the books is selected I press a button called return book that should make the book removed from the list.

I have a members class that has a return book method as follows

```
public void returnBook(Book aBook)
{
    currentLoans.remove(aBook);
    aBook.setBorrower(null);
}
```

On my main application I have the following code under the return book button

```
private void theButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
  //!!!Return book
  DefaultListModel model = (DefaultListModel) BooksOnLoan.getModel(); 
  Book selectedBook;
  selectedBook = (Book)BooksOnLoan.getModel();
  model.remove(selectedBook); 
}
```

As you can see I am quite not sure how to remove the item from the list once the button is clicked.

Comment: Does your code compile? If not, what errors do you get? If so, what happens when you run the program?

Comment: my code doesn't compile, however, I am trying to remove an item from the list using remove but when I try this it mentions this " Book cannot be converted to MenuComponent)
    method Container.remove(int) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; Book cannot be converted to int)"

Comment: @Sky From your last comment (not from the code in the question though) it seems like you are trying to remove from the _list_. You cannot do it like that - with Container or Component methods that are mentioned, you must remove the element from the list model. See my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

The method "remove" from DefaultListModel works with index, so you first need to get the index of the element that you want to remove and provide that to the remove method. You can use methods on your list for that: getSelectedIndex method for single selection mode (you will get -1 if there is no selection), or getSelectedIndices for multiselect.

If in any case your list stays the same after this, you need to refresh GUI after the model has been changed. Although I am almost certain that you need not do that, but keep this principle in mind for future.